# Printing PDF file with Custom Page size

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

How can I print PDF file without changing the page size? I use the code below but it changes the paper size.

```
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = FilePath;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
        p.Kill();
```

Comment: What does it change, from what into what?

Comment: Originally the page size of the pdf file is 7.81inx4.51in but when I print, it was adjusted to the default size of the printer which is A4 if I'm not mistaken.